# How to address error "Did not load script at 'script name' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, mime-types

I have a fairly simple Angular 1.x app that was working fine until i upgraded to Safari 11. Now, it doesn't work because almost all of the js files are blocked.

The same was true for CSS files, but removing the "rel" attribute and adding type="text/css" fixed the CSS issues.

For the JS files, I've made sure to add type="text/javascript" to the script tags. I also just tried adding ./ to the beginning of the src's for giggles and they still won't load.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: Is the server not setting the correct types?

Comment: I'm testing the app locally using nam live-server. It's worked fine until Safari update

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my prior comment. I meant npm live-sever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I want to just delete the question but I hope maybe this answer will still be helpful to someone.

So, my problem was actually that I had a bad clone of my project and it was missing files!

However, for anyone having the same issue:

ensuring that type="text/css" for stylesheets and type="text/javascript" did fix the issue. (for the files that actually existed)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that a response header with the name `X-Content-Type` or `X-Content-Type-Optionas` has the `text/javascript` value instead of `nosniff`.

It is simple to make a workaround locally using [Charles Proxy Rewrite tool](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/)

[image]